# What is the most efficient method to paint pixels on screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have a list of points each point present pixel on the screen, I wanna to painting these pixel on the screen ,  first. I try do it with list of row and colums with I sizedbox inside container it's worked but the performers was so bad because I have like 10 thousands widget in my widget tree, then I replaced the last method with. CustomerPanter with square for each pixel, the performance was quite better but I still got some junkie frames, so I'm looking for low level access to allowed me to paint into the screen directly so I could increase my app performance

Comment: Consider setting the pixels into an in memory bitmap, then render the bitmap either as an image widget, or using draw image onto the canvas.

Comment: sorry,  I had tried your method but the single image with 240 pixels take to long to build, ```class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final list = [.....]  //  a list of bytes

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 24), (timer) {
      setState(() {
          mycode...
      });
    });
    return Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(list));
  }
}
``` this is my demo and I can't even see this pic on this screen

Comment: Does your byte array start with a valid BMP header?

Comment: Btw, you are starting a new timer each time build runs. You'll end up with an increasing number of timers all firing every few milliseconds. You should start the timer once in initState.